# Transition from SCNScene to SKScene: Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `viewController` that is a `SCNScene`, when an object is pressed I want the application to take you to another scene that is an `SKScene`, is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to use "`SCNView.presentScene`", however the the scene that it's being directed towards also needs to be a `SCNScene`, but it is an `SKScene`.

Answer (score 1):

SCNScene is not a viewController
and you dont need a scene to present a scene
instead use a current view instance to call .present method

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly what you really want but hope this can be helpful. You can create scene and adding to View like this:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

let skView = self.view as! SKView

scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
skView.presentScene(scene)
```